# Logging kubernetes container log to azure event hub using fluent-bit - error while loading shared libraries: librdkafka.so

Tags: kubernetes, azure-eventhub, fluentd

$ kubectl create namespace logging

$ kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fluent/fluent-bit-kubernetes-logging/master/fluent-bit-service-account.yaml

$ kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fluent/fluent-bit-kubernetes-logging/master/fluent-bit-role.yaml

$ kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fluent/fluent-bit-kubernetes-logging/master/fluent-bit-role-binding.yaml

$ kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fluent/fluent-bit-kubernetes-logging/0.13-dev/output/kafka/fluent-bit-configmap.yaml

After this getting error

/fluent-bit/bin/fluent-bit: error while loading shared libraries: librdkafka.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

And fluent-bit pod is creating but in CrashLoopBackOff

Ref - https://github.com/fluent/fluent-bit-kubernetes-logging

Can any one suggest how to resolve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. Deploy all from master branch. You seem to be installing Kafka configmap from developer branch while the rest is from master.
2. You skipped to create a Kafka deamonset. Do below.

   $ kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fluent/fluent-bit-kubernetes-logging/master/output/kafka/fluent-bit-ds.yaml

Comment: i am struggling to configure azure eventhub endpoints to kafka configmap 
Can you help out on this 

  output-kafka.conf: |
    [OUTPUT]
        Name           kafka
        Match          *
        Brokers        bootstrap.kafka:9092
        Topics         ops.kube-logs-fluentbit.stream.json.001

changed to

        Brokers        xxxx-eventhub-app.servicebus.windows.net:9093
        Topics         xxxx-container-monitor-log

Comment: [ warn] [output:kafka:kafka.0] internal queue is full, retrying in one second
 [ warn] [engine] failed to flush chunk '1-1618373581.858657809.flb',
Failed to produce to topic xxxx-container-monitor-log: Local: Queue full

Comment: Can you open another thread for this issue? It is pure Kafka client configuration issue. Not related to this topic.

Comment: now it was resolved and working for all container
Tanks for support